# How to create a base observer class in typescript/react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I have a common pattern my react app where I have many components that observe the same model.  The code for each component looks like this:

```
export interface IAppModel {
    someLocation: { x: number, y: number } ;
    doSomething: () => void;
};


@inject("appModel")
@observer
export default class MyComponent
  extends React.Component<{appModel?: IAppModel}> { ... }
```

I would like to simplify this by declaring a base class like this:

```
@inject("appModel") @observer class AppComponentBase extends React.Component<{appModel?: IAppModel}> {}

export default class MyComponent extends AppComponentBase { ... }
```

This gives me a runtime error: *Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null*

Not sure if/how this can work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from `IAppModel`
Please share it

Comment: OK, Added to original post

Comment: Look [provider_inject](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/inject.html)